# Why does passing a list of metrics when compiling Tensorflow models result in an InvalidArgumentError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm learning Tensorflow and I'm trying to pass a list of metrics to be evaluated when I compile classification models in a loop, like the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#define_the_model_and_metrics) in the documentation.

However, when I pass a list like:

```
METRICS = [
    keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
    keras.metrics.AUC(name='prc', curve='PR')
]

def compile_model(model, X_train, y_train, X_val=None, y_val=None, callbacks=None, batch_size=1000, epochs = 10, optimizer='adam', loss_func=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy']):

    # Copy the model
    mdl = model
    mdl.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss_func, metrics = metrics)

    # Fit model
    if (X_val is not None) and (y_val is not None):
        mdl.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks,
                validation_data = (X_val, y_val))
    else:
        mdl.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks)

    return mdl

# Compile model
model = compile_model(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=1000, epochs = 10, metrics=METRICS)
```

I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'metrics/tp/AssignAddVariableOp/resource_1' with dtype resource
     [[node metrics/tp/AssignAddVariableOp/resource_1 (defined at /opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6163]
```

If I try to compile the model with a list of metrics like

```
model = compile_model(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=1000, \
epochs = 10, metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'), keras.metrics.AUC(name='prc', curve='PR')] )
```

the models are able to compile without any issues. None of the related questions I've seen about these placeholder tensors involve Keras' metrics. Why does the error only occur when I try to pass the metrics that way?

Comment: Is the target variable binary? because AUC and PR curves are quality measures for binary. I just tried executing the example(imbalanced_data classification on tensorflow site)  it was working fine. This error occurs when you are not feeding the values to placeholders.

Comment: Yes, the target is binary. I'm not sure where (or what) the placeholders are to feed values into them :)